# referential integrity violation in MySQL server , how to solve it?

Tags: mysql, sql, referential-integrity

I have created a simple table in MySQL with circular integrity . But It violates the circular integrity. It Shows successful Query execution but when tried to insert data , even though it violates the constraints its inserted.
[Here is the screenshot of m mysql console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL0bx.png)

[image]

Comment: Foreign key support No https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

it may be because of the storage engine. By default it may using MyISAM.

Try creating your structure with innodb engine as follows

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bb` (
  `ssn` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `suppperssn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ssn`),
  FOREigN KEY (`suppperssn`) REFERENCES bb(`ssn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
CREATE TABLE `bb` (
  `ssn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `superssn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ssn`),
  KEY `superssn` (`superssn`),
  CONSTRAINT `bb_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`superssn`) REFERENCES `bb` (`ssn`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of value at first insert statement, it should be

```
insert into bb values(1,2);
```

Also,
not using column names isn't a good practice